# Webserver and Mailbox point to different DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I have two service providers and one domain.

1. Domain registered in Godaddy
2. I have 1and1 and AWS.

For A2Hosting: I want to use Free Mailbox (Not the paid version) - I can register as External domain and create mailbox.

For AWS: I want it for my website. (All setup and ready)

Question here is:

How do I setup my DNS to make it work such a way:

1. when I type: http://www.myexampledomain.com - It should go to my AWS account
2. When I send an email to somename@myexampledomain.com - It should go to my 1and1 mailbox?

Is it possible? If so how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow your email server instructions for setting up the DNS records. This consists of MX (always) and optional TXT and SRV records.

For your domain name, the web server will be setup using DNS Type A records. Subdomains can be setup with A or CNAME records.

Email is setup using DNS Type MX records.

These records will be created in your GoDaddy DNS server control panel. Your email provider will have instructions for the type of DNS records that they require you to create in the DNS server for your domain name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I just forward MX record on AWS and create an external domain on 1and1.com? Will it work?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "forward MX record on AWS". The MX records are created in your DNS servers for your domain name. The MX records have values that your email provider gives you. Follow their documentation. There are some good YouTube videos on setting up email records in a DNS server.